# (401) Unauthorized SharePoint - C# Console Application Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, 401

**Unable to upload the documents in SharePoint Online using a console application. Any solution to this problem?**

```
public static void SaveFileToSharePoint(string fileName)
    {

       string Url = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites";
       string libraryName = "Shared Documents";

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(Url))
                        {
                            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                            foreach (char c in "*****".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("xxxx@xxxgmail.onmicrosoft.com",
                                passWord);
                            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString() + "/" + fileName.Split('\\')[1], fileStream, true);
                            }
                        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer this link once. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637504/upload-file-to-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-library) contains the code for authenticating with your SharePoint Online and upload a file into the given library.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName"))
            {
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "YourPassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@domain.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Applications\PropertyMaster.xlsx"); // this is my sample file path
                newFile.Url = "testFile.xlsx"; // file name which should be created in library

                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Library Name");
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code worked for me.

[image: My Output image]

I have created a console application. Still you have any issue then inform me.

Comment: I tried that code also but it's of no use.

Comment: I have implemented the above code and it worked for me. Let  me know the error or issue which you are facing.

Comment: @Amitabha What permissions does your user (xxxx@xxxgmail.onmicrosoft.com) have on the site? You may want to also check out this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70562/savebinarydirect-throws-unauthorized-when-the-client-object-model-works-fine. There are a couple ways to upload files via CSOM. See this MSDN post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904536.aspx.

Comment: @Aakash Thanks for the code. It worked, i was doing a stupid mistake in the url (first time in sharepoint).

Comment: please don't forget to mark as answer so that other people can get help :-)